# Run Windows Explorer on remote system from its cygwin shell through SSH

Tags: windows, ssh, shell, cygwin, windows-explorer

Please consider my problem :)

1) I Have a Windows 7 - x64 system with cygwin installed and SSHD running.
2) From another Windows machine , from futty, SSH to the above machine.
3) Command "TaskKill /IM explorer.exe /F" to kill explorer. **Success**!
4) Command "/cygdrive/c/Windows/sysnative/cmd.exe /c start /B explorer.exe" to start explorer. **Failed**!!
From task manager I can see that the **explorer** process is **running**, but no visible "proof" for it. No icons , **No task bar**.
5) (optional) Command "ps -W | grep explorer | cut -c 31-36 | paste -s -d," to see running explorer process Id from cygwin shell itself.

After searching google and StackOverFlow, the command mentioned in step 4 worked manually on direct cygwin shell on target system.

Primary:: My question here is, is there any command to replace in Step 4, so that we have a "neat" Windows Explorer process up and running ?!

Secondary:: My aim is to remotely kill and start windows explorer properly, Any methods for doing it ?! (Ofcourse, through cygwin - direct (most preferred), power shell or cmd commands )

Advanced Thanks!
- Rx3 -

Comment: Instead of saying windows 7, if I say windows server does it count! :P
And If I say, I have some unshareable automation task to do on it with the said requirement, does that count ?! omg!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no.  There is no way to run remote windows applications over `ssh`. There is no protocol that would support that (unlike on Linux, where is still the ancient X11). If you want to play with Windows windows, use RDP or how is that thing called.

Even if you are not interested in the actual window, the cygwin is running in different session (I hope windows has also such concept) to the actual desktop so running applications across the sessions is also not a good idea.

I would just kill it and rely that it will get started automatically again.

Comment: Thank you for the response :). I ended up killing the open explorer  windows instead.

Comment: Thanks for not being a pseudo-genius (like the guys above!) and helping to find the solution for the question. You guys are the real ones, whom people trust.